# Plotting piecewise functions maple

Tags: math-software, maple

How would I plot the following equation in maple?

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{if } x\in\mathbb{Q}, \\ 0, & \text{if } x\notin \mathbb{Q}. \end{cases}$$

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call this "piecewise" ...

Comment: I don't think that plotting this will work out particularly well... You'll either simply get a filled rectangle (if you do a *line* plot), or two lines, one at $y=0$ and one at $y=1$ (if you do a *point* plot). Or, maple might get horribly confused, and draw something else...

Comment: If they develope a graphics card that supports infinite resolution, perhaps somebody makes software to plot this function. A virus with a virus-sized pincel would be as unable to draw it as an elephant with a paintbrush.

Comment: A plot on computer usually assumes a bit of continuity.  Here the function is continuous nowhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really, as the commenters said. The graph of this function exists in the Platonic universe of ideas, but it cannot exist in our physical Universe. As a corollary, Maple is unable to show it to you.

Here is something you can do to catch the passing shadow of this function on the wall of our cave. The function $f$ is the [pointwise limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function) of the following kind:
$$f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \lim_{m\to\infty} (\cos(2\pi n! x))^{2m}$$

Take large $n,m$ and increase `numpoints` in the `plot` command:

```
n:=10; m:=500;
plot(cos(2*Pi*n!*x)^(2*m),x=-1..1,numpoints=10000);
```

[image: approximation to Dirichlet]